# Superfish and Flash again. Please help

Tags: flash, superfish

I know there's a lot about this issue but i'm embedding flash like this: (i don't know how t escape code so sorry if it looks weird)

```
   var flashvars = {}
   var params = { 
      base: "."
   }              
   var attributes = {}
   swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.zakochaniwfotografii.pl/html5/slideshow/ceremonia.swf", "flashcontent", "932", "450", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

and the flash appears in here

```
    div class="imageHolder" id="flashcontent"

    /div
```

You can see all of it here: http://www.zakochaniwfotografii.pl/html5/fotografia-weselna.php
I'm trying to setup my website but only Firefox displays this well.

I solved the issue on my index page zakochaniwfotografii.pl/html5/ but here i am embeding flash differently due to a different gallery, so i cannot do it the same on the underpages.

I'd appreciate your help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. For those with the same issue you need to add

```
params.wmode = "opaque";
```

tot the whole thing like so

```
   var flashvars = {}
   var params = { 
      base: "."
   }        
   params.wmode = "opaque";  
   var attributes = {}
   swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.zakochaniwfotografii.pl/html5/slideshow/engage.swf", "flashcontent", "932", "450", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

The result works in any browser: http://www.zakochaniwfotografii.pl/html5/ceremonia-slubna.php

Thank you!
Alex